# React Native List onPress sending wrong object using "i"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a list in react native and each element is clickable. When the element is clicked it navigates to another Scene and passes an object based on the element that was clicked and the value of 'i'.

But when clicking an element it always send the object that 'i' ended on. Which makes sense.

```js
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     items: this.props.items
    };
  }

makeList() {
  var items = []
  for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
      items.push(
        <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        onPress={() => this.sendItem(this.state.items[i])}>
            <View>this.state.items[i].name</View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
  }
  return items;
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.makeList()}
    </View>
  );
}

sendItem(item) {
  this.props.navigate(item);
}
```

So whenever any one of the items are clicked it always send 'Four'.

How can i fix this so that it sends the correct object?

Thank you!

Comment: `this.state.items` doesn't exist in your given code. Please detail the code as you have written it. Currently, you show no state object in your code.

Comment: @CarlMarkham down see how that changes anything but there ya go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` doesn't create a new variable for each iteration of the loop, so you're mutating the same `i` variable. When the loop ends, `i === 3`, and so that's what the `onPress` callback sees. You can use `let` instead.

```
for (let i = 0; i <3; i++) {
```

Or you can avoid loops.

```
const items = Array.from({length: 3}, (x, i) => {
  return <TouchableOpacity ... />;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! changing to 'let' fixed the problem. Now i know what let does as well!